# Speed difference reading parquet files between pandas and pyarrow

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I am trying to understand why there is a such a difference in speed between reading a parquet file directly to Pandas using pd.read_parquet and Pyarrow.parquet pq.read_table() It seems strange as I believe Pandas is using Pyarrow under the hood.

What am I missing?

pandas version 1.1.5

pyarrow version 3.0.0

For example reading the same file from S3

```
start = datetime.datetime.now()
pd_df = pd.read_parquet("s3://" + bucket_name + "/" + key)
total = datetime.datetime.now() - start
print(total)
0:00:27.634829
```

and

```
start = datetime.datetime.now()
pa_tab = pq.read_table("s3://" + bucket_name + "/" + key)
total = datetime.datetime.now() - start
print(total)
0:16:18.545071
```

**Edit**

I tried reading the file from the local drive and get much better performance from pyarrow.

```
start = datetime.datetime.now()
pd_df = pd.read_parquet("~/injury_problem/athlete_18931.parquet")
total = datetime.datetime.now() - start
print(total)
0:00:27.224333
```

vs

```
start = datetime.datetime.now()
pa_tab = pq.read_table("/Users/warwick/injury_problem/athlete_18931.parquet")
total = datetime.datetime.now() - start
print(total)
0:00:19.376693
```

Comment: One difference between both is that the pandas version also includes the conversion from pyarrow Table to pandas DataFrame (although I wouldn't expect that to explain the big difference). Further, it seems a bit fishy that using `pd.read_parquet` you see almost the same time for local vs from S3 (or is the file size different?). One other difference is that pandas is using fsspec to interact with S3.

Comment: @joris thanks for your comment I tried with fsspec and that did the trick. If you want add that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @warwickh, so the bottom line is not using the pyarrow default S3 bindings?

Comment: @taras it's not easy, as it also depends on other factors (eg reading full file vs selecting subset of columns, whether you are using pyarrow.dataset or not, etc). But with the current pyarrow release, using s3fs' filesystem can indeed be beneficial when using `pq.read_table`. This will be fixed in a future pyarrow release, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-12428

Comment: Documentation might help: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/3.0/python/filesystems.html